# How do I nohup a subprocess spawned from a commandline?

Tags: bash, stderr

I have a bit complex to explain issue that I have ran into:

1. I have a long running **nohupped** process that redirects its stderr into a file.
2. However, I use a subprocess to stamp the stderr with a timestamp.
3. The above mentioned subprocess unfortunately is not nohupped (my bad)!
4. Now, How do I get this subprocess somehow nohupped and get the stderr preserved and keep coming to the file even after I log out. I have to logout of the server.

The commandline in question looks something like this:

```
$ nohup myscript.sh -op1 val1 -op2 val2 -op3 val3 >mystderr.txt 2> >(while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done > n100l1800g0.5.err ) < /dev/null &
```

The above technique of stamping stderr is learned recently right here at stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page for the `nohup` I have  says  `nohup [ options ] command [arg ...]`.

I remember reading someplace that `nohup` does not process pipelines, which I think is what you have.

Try remaking your pipeline processes as a script that accept the arguments and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Put your commands into a shell script and nohup the script.

so if *yourscript* contains :

```
#!/bin/bash
myscript.sh -op1 val1 -op2 val2 -op3 val3 >mystderr.txt 2> >(while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done > n100l1800g0.5.err ) < /dev/null
```

then from the command line

> $ nohup yourscript &

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thank you for answering, But this does not answer the question. The question was that the command has already been executed and after that he wants to convert the process to one with nohup.